# How I can reverse the content of a table?

Tags: t-sql

I need a general procedure that can reverse the content of a table.

Basically I have a ragged table (a `dimension table` for an `OLAP DB`) built from top level and I need to convert into from a bottom level perspective.

How can do it?

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+
| Co1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
|   1 | 9765 | 1234 | A    |      |
|   2 | 9765 | 1235 | A    |      |
|   3 | 9765 | 1235 |      |      |
|   4 | 9764 | 4567 | 789  | A1   |
|   5 | 9764 |      |      |      |
|   6 | 9764 | 4568 | 3453 | A2   |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
|  Co1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| A    | 1234 | 9765 |    1 |      |
| A    | 1235 | 9765 |    2 |      |
| 1235 | 9765 |    3 |      |      |
| A1   |  789 | 4567 | 9764 |    4 |
| 9764 |    5 |      |      |      |
| A2   | 3453 | 4568 | 9764 |    6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Do you have only five columns in the table?

Comment: Hi Andrei, I have different tables with different deep. So Column number could change (but usually ranging from 2 to 10). Anyway also a procedure where i manually edit the script to take in account the depth could works.

Comment: Hi Tim, table 1 is the output of an OLAP dimension. If you read the table from left to right you have an hierarchy. you can drill-down (don't consider Col 1 for this explanation since it's the hierarchy sequential number). Using OLAP naming convention element '1234' (row1, col2) is a top element while 'A' (row1, col4) is the leaf element. Unfortunatly I need to import data into another OLAP tool that require leaf element in first column (see table 2) .

Answer (score 0):

if I properly understand the example tables you have provided, you can just insert them in reverse order if you are creating a new table with the data, or you can simply give the fields new names in query results by providing an alias using the `AS` keyword.

Both shown together to be more concise and because they won't conflict with one another. If you only need to select the data with different column names, then you can remove the `INSERT` clause. If you are creating a new, table you may omit the alias.

```sql
INSERT INTO table2
  ( Col5, Col4, Col3, Col2, Col1 )
SELECT
  Col1 as Col5
, Col2 as Col4
, Col3
, Col4 as Col2
, Col5 as Col1
FROM table1
```

Comment: Hi Philip i could not take into accout the column order. Position are relative. For row 1 is  col4 but for row 5 is col2 and so on.